# Show these sets are disjoint

Tags: general-topology

This is a part of a much bigger theorem I'm trying to prove, but I'm stuck with a little finishing argument which is very reasonable (is it? I sure hope it's true tho) but I can't get it to be done. I've spent so much time so explaining my "way" seems a bit redundent. I am not going to give the exact problem or the whole of it, but just simplify it to the main dificulty in hand.

Assume $Y$ is a compact hausdorff topological space. $f:Y\to X$ a continuous open map. $x_1\not=x_2\in X$ and $f^{-1}(x_1)\subset \tilde U, f^{-1}(x_2)\subset \tilde V$ for $\tilde U, \tilde V \subset Y$ open and disjoint. Also assume $U_1$ is an (open) neighborhood of $x_1$ and likewise $U_2$ of $x_2$. Assume $A_1,\ldots A_n\subset Y$, $B_1,\ldots B_m\subset Y$ open sets such that $A_i \cap A_j =\emptyset, B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset $  for $i\not=j$, and $f^{-1}(U_1)=\cup A_i, f^{-1}(U_2)=\cup B_i$. Also $\forall 1\leq i\leq n,\:1\leq j\leq m:\:f|_{A_i}, f|_{B_j}$ are homeomorphisms onto $U_1, U_2$ respectively

Let $U=\cap_{i=1}^n f(A_i\cap \tilde U), V=\cap_{i=1}^m f(B_i\cap \tilde V)$.

Additional information that could maybe be usefull: for every $z\in U\cup V$ you could assume $f^{-1}(z)$ is finite (can't assume tho that it is of cardinality less than $n$ or $m$).

**prove that U,V are disjoint**.

I imagine this similar to covering space (**if you prefer / it is quite helpfull/necessary, just assume Y is a covering space and f has finite fibers** - I could make adjustments), as $A_i$ stand above $U_1$ and $B_j$ above $U_2$. thing is that $U$ is given by projections of a neighborhood of $f^{-1}(x_1)$, and $V$ of $f^{-1}(x_2)$ which should also lead to disjoint images as this is a local homemorphism.

Any idea would be blessed/
my fear is that this could just maybe be false, for $U_1 \cap U_2$ could be too big, and it could be problematic to fix them to be like this.
**I also udnerstand that if it is not true, giving a counter example could be slightly hard, so comments with a "feeling" that my claim is wrong could possible be helpful comming from the right person**

Comment: is X Hausdorff? If not you might get a counterexample. If yes you might use that f is also closed.

Comment: @Mirko: $X$ isn't hausdorff (actually, one of the things i'm trying to get is that $X$ is hausdorff)

Comment: Did anyone have any luck?